# Solve this equation: $\frac{f(x)}{\int_{0}^{x_1} f(x)dx}=\frac{g(x)}{\int_{0}^{x_1} g(x)dx}$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ or some relations between the two functions knowing that 
>   $$
> \frac{f(x)}{\int_0^{x_1} f(x)dx}
>  = \frac{g(x)}{\int_0^{x_1} g(x)dx},
> \quad \forall x \in (0, x_1), \ \forall x_1 \in (0, x_{\max}).
> $$

One solution is $g(x)=a f(x)$ where $a$ is a constant.

I would be intrested in other solutions less evident.

Comment: Its useful to write it on the form $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\int_0^{x_1} f(y)dy}{\int_0^{x_1} g(y)dy}$. Note that the right hand side does not depend on $x$.